# Check if string is serialized in PHP

Tags: php, serialization

I am in the middle of building a cache layer for the Redis DB to my application and I have come to the point where's it's about to take care of arrays.

I wonder if there's any good (high performance!) way of controlling an string to be serialized or not with PHP?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean? a string intern pool? PHP doesn't have that (yet)

Comment: I can't really tell what you're looking for from the wording of your question. The title made it sound like you just wanted a way to check if any given string is a serialized representation of something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check to see if a string is serialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369936/check-to-see-if-a-string-is-serialized)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$array = @unserialize($string);
if ($array === false && $string !== 'b:0;') {
    // woops, that didn't appear to be anything serialized
}
```

The `$string !== 'b:0;'` checks to see if the serialized string may have been the value `false`. If this check is important to you you may want to `trim` the serialized string or otherwise preprocess it to make sure this works.

Comment: you don't have to take the risk, you can check error_get_last

Comment: @Artefacto This may or may not be useful, as it can be hard to tell whether the last error was really thrown here or sometime earlier. A better way may be to look at the serialized string to see if it looks like a single serialized `false`. Anyway, who serializes `false` values? ;)

Comment: Hi Deceze! Sounds great, I will definitely try that out! Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for alternative, this code worked for me as helper function for Laravel framework and then you can call it anywhere.

```
if(!function_exists('isSerialized')){
    function isSerialized($string){
        $tempString = '';
        $array = @unserialize($string);
        if(is_array($array)){
            foreach ($array as $k=>$i){
                //do something with data
                $tempString .= $k . $i['something'];
            }
        } else {
            $tempString = $string;
        }
        return $itemString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function to check if a string weather serialized or not. The link of the function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_serialized/

```
function is_serialized( $data, $strict = true ) {
        // If it isn't a string, it isn't serialized.
        if ( ! is_string( $data ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        $data = trim( $data );
        if ( 'N;' === $data ) {
            return true;
        }
        if ( strlen( $data ) < 4 ) {
            return false;
        }
        if ( ':' !== $data[1] ) {
            return false;
        }
        if ( $strict ) {
            $lastc = substr( $data, -1 );
            if ( ';' !== $lastc && '}' !== $lastc ) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $semicolon = strpos( $data, ';' );
            $brace     = strpos( $data, '}' );
            // Either ; or } must exist.
            if ( false === $semicolon && false === $brace ) {
                return false;
            }
            // But neither must be in the first X characters.
            if ( false !== $semicolon && $semicolon < 3 ) {
                return false;
            }
            if ( false !== $brace && $brace < 4 ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        $token = $data[0];
        switch ( $token ) {
            case 's':
                if ( $strict ) {
                    if ( '"' !== substr( $data, -2, 1 ) ) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } elseif ( ! str_contains( $data, '"' ) ) {
                    return false;
                }
                // Or else fall through.
            case 'a':
            case 'O':
            case 'E':
                return (bool) preg_match( "/^{$token}:[0-9]+:/s", $data );
            case 'b':
            case 'i':
            case 'd':
                $end = $strict ? '$' : '';
                return (bool) preg_match( "/^{$token}:[0-9.E+-]+;$end/", $data );
        }
        return false;
    }
```