# Try except in PHP

Tags: php

How could I perform the equivalent to an open `try:this except:pass` in Python?

I have the following code:

```
$banana = true;
unserialize($banana);
```

And it returns the error:

> Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

Which is expected, as I fed it a boolean.

This is just an example; I am using unserialize(), but I'm not purposely feeding it booleans. I need it to work this way.

Comment: Have you looked at [exception handling?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: If you're looking specifically for a solution with `unserialize`: possible duplicate of [Check if string is serialised in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878218/check-if-string-is-serialized-in-php); if you're generally looking for `try..catch`, this does not apply here since those aren't exceptions.

Comment: By default you cannot catch notices, warnings and errors (and a few others). You can only catch `Exception`s. Also, the warning in this question has nothing to do with your code. You never use `array_keys()` in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since unserialize doesn't throw an exception, there is nothing to catch.
One of the workarounds is using the silence operator (@) and check whether the
outcome of the unserialize method equals false.

```
$foo = @unserialize($bar);
if ($foo === false && $bar !== 'b:0;') {
    // Unserialize went wrong
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr) {
    throw new Exception($errstr, 0);
}, E_NOTICE);

try {
    $result = unserialize($banana); // correct
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result = array();  // default value
}
restore_error_handler();


print_r($result);
```

Comment: I like the approach but it's extremly resource intensive for such a simple problem

Comment: I'm very bad speak English but I thought that the author wanted to find the try/exept equivalent in python for this issue