# How to find out if a string is a serialized object/array or just a string?

Tags: php, serialization

Is there some reliable way to find out whether a string variable is just a string or a string representation of a serialized object/array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Check to see if a string is serialized?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369936/php-check-to-see-if-a-string-is-serialized)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can tell by looking at the format.  When you serialize an array, you get a string that looks like `a:1:{i:0;s:3:"foo"}`  And if you serialize an object, you get: `o:7:"myclass":1:{s:3:"foo";s:3:"bar";}`.

So if you want to test rudimentary, you can do these two regexes:

```
^a:\d+:{.*?}$
```

And

```
^o:\d+:"[a-z0-9_]+":\d+:{.*?}$
```

for arrays and objects respectively.

Note that this just checks for the generic form.  To tell if it's a valid serialized string, you need to run it through `unserialize()` and test the return `is_array($result)` and `is_object($result)`...

Comment: @andre: Yes, seriously.  Sometimes you may not want to unserialize for several reasons (for example, if the class name is not defined, or if it's expensive, etc).  It could be just a sanity check before storing the serialized string.  There are lots of reasons.  And if you know of a better one than regex without calling `unserialize`, I'm all ears...

Comment: if your string is that big that unserialize might be an heavy operation, don't you think the regex match will also be expensive? Anyways, thanks for explaining you reasons. :-)

Comment: @andre: it won't be nearly as expensive as the double-allocation of memory needed to unserialize (since you need to keep both the string and the new object/array in memory).  Sure, it'll be somewhat slow to walk, but those regex's are fairly efficient, so I wouldn't worry too much about them (there's virtually no backtracking necessary)...  But fair enough...

Answer (score 7):

You can call [`unserialize(string $str)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function: it returns `false`, if string cannot be unserialized.

Comment: have fun: `PHP Warning:  Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer in /root/hacked.php on line 5
object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (1) {
  ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=>
  string(8) "Poreikis"
}`

Comment: Use an ampersand in front to suppress the error messages (ie. @unserialize)

Comment: @Andrew `@` is not called ampersand. Ampersand is `&`

Comment: What if the string is `b:0;`? `unserialize` will return `false` but it is a valid serialized value.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks @developerbmw

Comment: IMPORTANT: Never ever unserialize raw user data since it can be used as an attack vector. [OWASP:PHP_Object_Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection)