# PHP serialize() ― specification

Tags: php, serialization

I am searching for the specification or an exact description about how the PHP serialize() function exactly works. All I could find for that topic is [that comment in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#66147).

Is there anywhere out there a more detailed description about how php implements this?

Comment: I guess the best specification is to look in the source code, but that might be a bit too much. What exactly do you want to know and what for?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I am especially interested in the details of the string serialization.

Comment: I guess you may have to look in the source code then. What do you want to know it for? If you're looking for a portable format to transport data with, JSON seems more universal

Comment: @Pekka웃 I am not looking for a portable format, I just try to find Strings that are serialized by php, so that they have the format: s:<length>:"<String>"; I want to make sure that my regexp wont miss any hit, or if it is possible at all to do that with an regexp. BTW. where can I find the source-code?

Comment: Depending on how many strings you are parsing (considering overhead), but if they are few, perhaps just trying to unserialize and checking if it succeeded might be the easier method..

Comment: @damienovereem I plan to parse a lot and I would like to do that with Java, so that is no option

Comment: You know about `unserialize()`?

Comment: There is a question/answer combo on stack that is about detecting if a string is a serialized string. Ircmaxell gave a decent answer on the matter. Maybe it will help out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748795/how-to-find-out-if-a-string-is-a-serialized-object-array-or-just-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To truly know how PHP handles serialized strings, one would need to dig in the sourcecode as suggested by Pekka 웃 in the comments.

Try starting at: http://lxr.php.net/search?q=PHP_FUNCTION+serialize&project=PHP_5_4 which gives a convenient way to search the sources.

This link comes from http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/16/Understanding-PHPs-internal-function-definitions.html which explains how to find specific function definitions in the php source.

Goodluck!

Comment: I chose this answer as the best because it delivers the best links to background information. Unfortunately it turned out that parsing those serialized strings with (not with php) is more a guessing and error prone too, but I could work out a working version with java. But in fact, corrupted Input will ever be able to break it, and since I was trying to process mysqldump files I had to realize that even all tests pass, it is possible to write another valid one that will fail. (f.i. a corrupted string that contains a serialzied object).

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to dig into this years ago. Warning: this blogpost is way old. I think the spec is still accurate, but ignore the content around it ;)

http://evertpot.com/133/ Jump to the section titled: *The serialized data format*.

Comment: finally, a real answer in this array of 'closed as not a real question' threads, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is sad, PHP do not provide specification of serialization.

You can explore source code https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/php_var.h, https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/var_unserializer.c . But it's hard to understand.

You can try to search implimentation on other languange. [JavaScript](http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/).