# Making a script that can recover a corrupt serialized string in PHP

Tags: php, serialization

Ok i have this:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:7:"address";s:52:"Elågåresgude 41, 2200 Københamm N";s:12:"company_name";s:14:"Kaffe og Kluns";s:9:"telephone";s:0:"";}}
```

This does not work with unserialize($string);

I know where the error is. It's the number in front os the address. It should not be 52, but 36.

I got to this number by counting the string (which gave me 33) and then plus with 1 on each å or ø that exists in the string.

When i replace 52 with 36, will it unseralize just fine.

Now i would like to write a script to do this for all my addresses.

But how can i even do this? Extract the address/company_name/telephone string, when its "corrupted"?

Comment: You could json_encode instead....

Comment: @Flukey: This is not JSON, OP wants to **deserialize**, not decode from JSON.

Comment: How do you get those corrupted strings? You should rather focus on the source of the problem than the error itself, if possible that is.

Comment: @Tadeck - Yes, I know. However, you are less likely to run into these problems of serialization if use you use json_encode instead. Furthermore, using json is better for portability. If OP has a db with lots of serialized php arrays and then one day he decides to switch over to python, he'll be somewhat.....screwed.

Comment: Looks like you may have an encoding issue, check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php and search for 'utf-8', there is a user contributed function that may help.

Comment: no problem here : http://codepad.viper-7.com/lLtAc0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function fix_corrupted_serialized_string($string) {
    $tmp = explode(':"', $string);
    $length = count($tmp);
    for($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {    
        list($string) = explode('"', $tmp[$i]);
        $str_length = strlen($string);    
        $tmp2 = explode(':', $tmp[$i-1]);
        $last = count($tmp2) - 1;    
        $tmp2[$last] = $str_length;         
        $tmp[$i-1] = join(':', $tmp2);
    }
    return join(':"', $tmp);
}
```

working demo:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/GNbM25

Comment: Good for the "length" problem, but like Marcus said, he should focus on the source of the problem.

Comment: There is question about length problem, and there is answer :) Anyways `serialize()` is only good for cache. I hate people who store data in this format (for ex.: 80% wordpress plugins)

Comment: Thank you this worked prima! @racar i have already fixed the source of the problem

Comment: So now instead of trying to resolve the root of the problem, you are going to add the overhead of an extra function?

Comment: @DigitalPrecision eh no i have resolved the root of the problem, but the damage the problem did, is what i was looking for to resolve/fix. Which I have now, thanks to peters answer. Sorry forgot to accept

Comment: @Karem: Ah. Glad you were able to fix the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the function in dealing with multi-byte characters. You might also want to try [explicitly encoding the string as utf-8](https://www.php.net/utf8-encode) before serializing it.

As a workaround, you could [base64 encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) the address before serializing it, then [base64 decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) it when you unserialize it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a classic case of someone trying to perform a shortcut when updating a value in a serialized string.  The lesson swiftly learned to avoid this headache is to unserialize your data, modify your value(s), then re-serialize it.

I feel regular expressions afford a more direct approach for *trying* to parse the corrupted serialized string.  To be perfectly clear, my snippet will only update the byte/character counts; if you have a serialized string that is corrupted by some other means, this will not be the remedy.

Here is a simple `preg_replace_callback()` call that only captures the value substring and unconditionally replaces all byte counts in the serialized string:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nXRaW))

```
$corrupted_byte_counts = <<<STRING
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:7:"address";s:52:"Elågåresgude 41, 2200 Københamm N";s:12:"company_name";s:14:"Kaffe og Kluns";s:9:"telephone";s:0:"";}}
STRING;

$repaired = preg_replace_callback(
        '/s:\d+:"(.*?)";/s',
        function ($m) {
            return 's:' . strlen($m[1]) . ":\"{$m[1]}\";";
        },
        $corrupted_byte_counts
    );

echo "corrupted serialized array:\n$corrupted_byte_counts";
echo "\n---\n";
echo "repaired serialized array:\n$repaired";
echo "\n---\n";
print_r(unserialize($repaired));
```

Output:

```
corrupted serialized array:
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:7:"address";s:52:"Elågåresgude 41, 2200 Københamm N";s:12:"company_name";s:14:"Kaffe og Kluns";s:9:"telephone";s:0:"";}}
---
repaired serialized array:
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:7:"address";s:36:"Elågåresgude 41, 2200 Københamm N";s:12:"company_name";s:14:"Kaffe og Kluns";s:9:"telephone";s:0:"";}}
---
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [address] => Elågåresgude 41, 2200 Københamm N
            [company_name] => Kaffe og Kluns
            [telephone] => 
        )

)
```

[I've even gone a bit further to address a possible fringe case.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55074706/2943403)  Without implementing the pattern extension in that link, the above snippet will work as desired on strings with:

- multibyte characters
- newlines
- colons
- semicolons
- commas
- single quotes
- double quotes

It only breaks when a string to be matched contains `";` -- in which case, my above link attempts to address that possibility.

Answer (score -1):

I think one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369936/check-to-see-if-a-string-is-serialized) should be to test if unserialize worked. If not, delete it and reserialize it.

```
$yourserializestring = '...';

$data = @unserialize($yourserializestring);
if ($yourserializestring === 'b:0;' || $data !== false) {
    // Something didn't work, you should recreate it
} else {
    echo "ok";
}
```