# PHP Unserialize offset error when argument is only a simple string

Tags: php, serialization

I am asking question after applied SO Ans.

i am trying to Unserialize from a serialized string fetched from DB.

I am getting Error : Unserialize offset error

I have two case

**Same Code in both case:**

```
 $categories = preg_replace( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'",  $data['Member']['category'] );        
 var_dump($categories);  
 $cat_unserialize = unserialize($categories);
 var_dump($cat_unserialize );
```

**case 1 : when**

```
$data['Member']['category'] => Adventure Camps
```

**case 1 : Error:**

```
string 'Adventure Camps' (length=15)

Notice (8): unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 15 bytes

boolean false
```

**case 2 : when**

```
$data['Member']['category'] => a:4:{i:0;s:9:"Adventure";i:1;s:12:"Sports ";i:2;s:15:"Training";i:3;s:29:"Educational";}
```

**case 2 :** **No Error Code id Working Fine**

Comment: In case 1 you are trying to unserialize a string that isn't serialized - that being the issue? try '@unserialize' and compare it to 'false' to check if its serialized

Comment: Code is same in both condition .

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand but it seems that you're trying to `unserialize` something that have not serialized before. `Adventure Camps` is not serialized. Maybe something went wrong with your preg_replace function regarding `case 1`?

Comment: After reading your updated question's title -> you can't use `unserialize` on string which are not already `serialized`.
You'll have to serialize all the values (even if there's only one value and not several) or you'll have to check it first.

Comment: `Adventure Camps` is not a serialized string. it's JUST a string. if it was serialized, then it'd look more like `s:15:"Adventure Camps"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unserialize only works on a serialized string. You need to prevent the notice from printing when trying to unserialize a string that isn't a serialized array.

```
$cat_unserialize = @unserialize($categories);
```

Otherwise, I'm not sure why it would be a problem.
Then afterwards, before using the variable you can check if it's an array or string.

```
if(is_array($cat_unserialize)) {
    //do something with array.
}
else {
    //do something with string.
}
```

Also, I don't understand the preg_replace(). Why remove the elements that make the string serialized, and then try to unserialize it?

Comment: Using `@` is like knowing that there's a problem with the code but instead of solving it, just not giving a ***

Comment: There isn't a problem. Unless the information is being stored incorrectly. There is nothing being done wrong on the retrieval side.

Comment: With that being said, you can expand your answer using:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369936/check-to-see-if-a-string-is-serialized

Comment: Yeah that answer looks a lot better. But I really just don't understand the issue here, or why he's doing it this way. Like running the preg_replace() on it seems weird to me, so maybe I just misunderstood at first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the long option : this is from wordpress

```
<?php
function is_serialized( $data ) {
    // if it isn't a string, it isn't serialized
    if ( !is_string( $data ) )
        return false;
    $data = trim( $data );
    if ( 'N;' == $data )
        return true;
    if ( !preg_match( '/^([adObis]):/', $data, $badions ) )
        return false;
    switch ( $badions[1] ) {
        case 'a' :
        case 'O' :
        case 's' :
            if ( preg_match( "/^{$badions[1]}:[0-9]+:.*[;}]\$/s", $data ) )
                return true;
            break;
        case 'b' :
        case 'i' :
        case 'd' :
            if ( preg_match( "/^{$badions[1]}:[0-9.E-]+;\$/", $data ) )
                return true;
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Check to see if a string is serialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369936/check-to-see-if-a-string-is-serialized)