# Avoiding `Undefined Property` in PHP when using `isset()` in a callback?

Tags: php, warnings, trim, isset

I have written a `validation` trait for my model classes, as well as an error reporting library which formats and returns a JSON object of errors, warnings, etc.

In my `validation` trait, I have this method...

```
function hasValue($value)
{
  return (isset($value) && !(trim($value) === ''));
}
```

PHP will throw a warming if I just try to use `!(trim($value)` in a conditional that tells me the variable is undefined. So, you have to do this...

```
if (isset($value) && !(trim($value) === ''))
  //Do Something
```

I created this method to consolidate a very common task requiring two methods into a single method, but I am getting the same warning as if I had used the `trim()` method alone.

Is there a way to do this without turning off warnings?

**EDIT**

There seems to be some confusion. I need this to work for variables, and object properties. I'm attempting to turn this...

```
if (empty($obj->email) && $this->validateEmail($obj->email))
  //Do Something
```

Into this...

```
if ($this->validateEmail($obj->email))
  //Do Something
```

By having my `hasValue()` method to call on will, and inside the `validateEmail()` method.

Comment: You could try `(isset($value)) ? !(trim($value) === '') : false;` if you're trying to keep it all to one line

Comment: It's not that I CAN'T write it every time, I'm looking for readability and usability. I don't WANT to write it every time.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but I do such things like this...
`if ( (isset($value)) && (!empty($value))){$value = trim($value); do something } else {
// error value was not set or was set to null value
}`

Comment: I thought you were trying to avoid the PHP Warning you were getting from combining the isset() with the check on $value's value - what I said above should provide the same results your current hasValue function does, but won't push out the warning

Comment: `if(!empty($value)){}` [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), you can use `if(!empty(trim((string) $value))){}` if desired.

Comment: @Drew No, I'm just trying to consolidate both methods to one method on a trait. My one-liner works just as well as yours if I write it every time in an `if statement`.

Comment: @All, see my edit. I'm trying to have a simple, readable method that can be used on properties and variables, and can be called within callback functions.

Comment: @Allenph There is a way to suppress warning messages but believe me this is almost **never** desired. Its done by using the `@` sign before a statement or disable the warning messages from `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE)`. And if you need this, you're doing it *wrong*

Comment: @Xorifelse Right. I knew about that. I was wondering if there was a way to avoid doing anything wrong in the first place while still achieving my desired result.

Comment: Well, the first issue is that `(isset($value) && !(trim($value) === ''))` is evaluated as one. Remove the outer parenthesis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131197/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-allenph).

Comment: Have any of the 2 answers resolved your question? if so mark it, if they were useful at least have the curtsy to up vote.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that your function `hasValue()` evaluates both statements `isset($value)` and `!(trim($value) === '')` as **one**

Instead you should evaluate `!(trim($value) === '')` **if** `isset($value)` equals *true*. This is done by removing the outer parenthesis.

```
function hasValue($value){
  return isset($value) && !(trim($value) === '');
  # if this ^^^^ is false this ^^^^ is never executed and no warning generated.
}
```

That would resolve the warning, however `hasValue()` sounds more like a function to check if any variable has a value, perhaps do this instead:

```
function hasValue($value){
  return isset($value) && !empty($value) || is_string($value) && !empty(trim($value));
}

var_dump(hasValue(null));  // false
var_dump(hasValue(true));  // true
var_dump(hasValue(false)); // false
var_dump(hasValue([]));    // false
var_dump(hasValue(''));    // false
var_dump(hasValue(' '));   // false
var_dump(hasValue('a'));   // true

interface validateInterface{
  public static function validateEmail($email);
  public static function validateEmailObj();
}

trait validateTrait{
  static function validateEmail($email){
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); 
  }
  function validateEmailObj(){
    return filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); 
  }
}

# Implementing an interface is not required, but recommended as traits are easily overwritten.
class MyClass implements validateInterface{
  use validateTrait;

  public $email;

  function __construct($email){
    if(self::validateEmail($email)){
      echo 'works statically inside';
    }

    $this->email = $email;
  }
}

$mail = 'some@email.com';

if(MyClass::validateEmail($mail)){
  echo 'works statically outside class';
}

if((new MyClass($mail))->validateEmailObj()){
  echo 'works with objects';
}
```

For a longer list of values what isset and empty does see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: Your code did not work for me as a method on my trait with variables or object properties.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a reasonable place to use the `@` modifier to suppress warnings.

```
if (@trim($value) != '')
```

If `$value` is undefined, it will be converted to an empty string. Using `@` suppresses the warning message when this happens.

Comment: This would still not solve the problem of using the function inside other validation functions like `validateEmail`.

Comment: I'd rather suggest type juggling, `if( !empty(trim((string)$value)) ){}`. Supressing is a [last](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1369946/4982088) resort

Comment: You need to use the `@` at the point where you reference the variable that might not be defined.